# chromedriver: various lib dependencies are missing on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit

Tags: ubuntu, selenium-chromedriver

so I'm trying to run chromedriver 2.20 downloaded from

```
 wget http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.20/chromedriver_linux64.zip
```

and on my ubuntu 14.04

```
 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I get the following message

```
./chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

digging in further I see that it's missing a whole bunch.

```
me@me:/var/chrome# ldd ./chromedriver
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc0e5aa000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f472eb63000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f472e95f000)
        libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f472e70e000)
        libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f472e406000)
        libnss3.so => not found
        libnssutil3.so => not found
        libsmime3.so => not found
        libnspr4.so => not found
        libgconf-2.so.4 => not found
        libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f472e0d1000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 

(0x00007f472ddcd000)
            libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f472dac7000)
            libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f472d8b1000)
            libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f472d693000)
            libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f472d2ce000)
            /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f472ed6b000)
            libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f472d0c6000)
            libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f472ce88000)
            libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f472cc69000)
            libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f472ca65000)
            libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f472c85f000)
```

So where can I Get the missing files?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I needed the following packages installed with apt/apt-get:

- libglib2.0-0
- libnss3
- libx11-6

I've been working on Ubuntu 16.04, so this might need slight adjustment for 14.04. Depending on how stripped down your installation is, you might also need libpcre or libstdc++, but they have probably already come with other packages.

You will probably also need to install chrome, which should bring those packages in anyway.