# Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488774)

Tags: ruby, scripting, watir

I'm trying to use Watir gem for writing scripts in ruby but the following code gives an error:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
```

Error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488774 (7e15618d1bf16df8bf0ecf2914ed1964a387ba0b),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.5 x86_64)
```

Please let me know the solution to the above issue.

Comment: do you have chrome installed on the machine, and added to $PATH?

Answer (score 2):

Remember,

You also need to have chrome installed on the machine in order for Selenium Chrome Driver to work.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some libraries which the the version of `chromedriver` you're trying to install depends on. You need to install these libraries to start `chromedriver`.

How did I solve this?

I SSH'd into my testing environment and ran `chromedriver` (I am using the latest version at the time of this answer: 2.35 on Ubuntu Trusty 14.04)

```
chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open ...
```

This is the Network Security Service library. Other versions may require some other libraries to be installed. Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38689924/393021) for more on this.

So I installed the library using `apt-get`.

p.s: Make sure you have Chrome installed in the box too. If you're using CircleCI, checkout [this tip](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/installing-chrome-inside-of-your-docker-container/9067/4).

Answer (score 0):

This means that your script is unable to find the Chrome <strike>driver</strike> browser executable. Make sure that you have downloaded the Chrome browser from [here](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html). Additionally, from the [ChromeDriver Capabilities docs](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities),

> Path to the Chrome executable to use (on Mac OS X, this should be the actual binary, not just the app. e.g., '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome')

Comment: this isn't a problem with chromedriver, but with Chrome itself.

Comment: can you explain why you think my answer is incorrect? It looks pretty similar to your own comment (which I regrettably did not see until I posted my answer). The error states "cannot find Chrome binary", which is what I addressed by suggesting that they either did not have their chrome binary or that they had not put it in an accessible location.

Comment: yea no problem!  absolutely.  so, chrome != chromedriver.  the OP has in their post `"chromedriver=2.31.488774"`  so we know that the chromedriver is being invoked correctly.  it looks like it's the connection between the chromedriver and the chrome browser itself.

Comment: I see. My mistake. So this means that they **do** have a chromedriver on their path, and it is just their call to it that is not working?

Comment: their call to it is working.  it just looks like chromedriver can't find the chrome browser.  you (in general) need to install both chrome AND chromedriver.  they are missing the former

Comment: Aha! Thank you. I will edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: my pleasure!  i will redact my downvote once it helps the OP :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add the location of the Chrome or Chromium app to your PATH. You likely tried to organize the apps on your Mac and did not put Chrome directly in the Applications folder.

However it came to be, the folder containing the Chrome or Chromium .app is not in your PATH. To remedy it, edit your ~/.bash_profile and add a line such as:
`export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Web"`
*In this example, I have put all of my browsers in a folder called "Web" inside of Applications.*

The more technical explanation is that chromedriver searches for a specific subpath within each entry in your PATH. The code that does it is here:
[Chromedriver Source Code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/35a93c1ca219f698ace9358df126429291a445a0/chrome/test/chromedriver/chrome/chrome_finder.cc#136)